# How to declare a map with class as key and an Array of java.lang.reflect.Constructor as value

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm building a map for caching purposes that contains a class as the key and the constructors of the class (Array) as the value.

How do I declare this map using generics?

```
private static Map<Class<T>, java.lang.reflect.Constructor<T>[]> classConstructorsCache = new HashMap<>();
```

Above statements gives a "T cannot be resolved to a type" error.

Comment: The short answer is you can't. You'll have to use a wildcard type (`<?>`) and cast as necessary. Note that `Class.getConstructors()` returns `Constructor<?>[]` because [generic arrays are unsafe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays).

Comment: Note that in a lot of cases, you’re likely want to use [`ClassValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ClassValue.html) instead of a `Map<Class,…>` for this kind of association.